# failed to save outputs: timed out waiting for the condition on Argo Workflow

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, argo-workflows

I'm running Argo workflow on Kubernetes.
And after I followed [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/kubeflow-amazon-eks/) to setup Jupyterhub, I started getting this error (never had the issue before using Jupyterhub) on the pods on Argo:
`failed to save outputs: timed out waiting for the condition`.

The job always fails if I add

```
  resources:
    limits:
      nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

But if gpu is not used, it sometimes succeeds (with retryStrategy after occasional failures).

Could someone help me out?

Comment: what is the Argo version?

Comment: the argo version is v2.3.0

Comment: could you paste logs of workflow controller?
`kubectl logs -n argo workflow-controller-XXXX`

Comment: @user3368526 when you add `resources:
    limits:
      nvidia.com/gpu: 1` it fails with the same error? did you try to increase `activeDeadlineSeconds` parameter for argo?

Comment: @A_Suh Thanks, yes it fails with that same error. I increased the activeDeadlineSeconds but it didn't change anything. It seems like the first step is not able to access or save the artifact in /tmp/ directory to share the artifacts across the steps.

Comment: can you list your pods? `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces o wide`

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Similar error message I am also getting with Argo 2.10.1 
"failed to save outputs: Failed to establish pod watch: timed out waiting for the condition"

Comment: Having same issue! Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

check if you have mentioned the ***serviceAccountName***

```
workflow.spec.serviceAccountName
```

for more info check this [link](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/4534)